# Include Magento More Than Once

Tags: php, shell, magento, command-line-interface

Perhaps and Odd Question, but I am looking to include Magento More than once... I better explain before you all palm slap your own faces.

I have a few Magento installs and want to manage some config values across all of them. First off wrote a script that included all Mage.php's, load the instance ups and then ran the program I needed, obviously this would never work and I'm going to see `Cannot redeclare class`

Of course I could write a wrapper that connects to the DB by reading the config values in the config.xml, but a preferable option would be to interface with Magento as an application.

First thoughts are to run each process in a different shell, but any help would be appreciated on the best method of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to run a script (which does some magic using Magento ) with different input configurations. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Then probably you need smth like this ?

```
for f in config1 config2 config3 config4
do
 echo "Processing $f"
 myScript $f &
done
```

Where `myScript` - is the script which does some magic with Magento and expects an input configuration
in this case it will be `$f` i.e. the iteration over `config1`, `config2`, etc. And finally the `&` at the end of the line will run your script in background withing separate processes.

Comment: might be, I'm not a `php` person. My example is a shell script example though.